# Ember-data how best to handle non validation errors

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the best way to handle 403 errors from ember-data?

I want to know the best way to handle non validation errors, for example I have a bit of code that might return an http 403 if the user is not allowed to perform the action.  For example, I have the following code:

```
contact.set 'something', 'something'

transaction = @get('store').transaction()

transaction.add(contact)

contact.one 'becameInvalid', (result) =>
  #display some error message

contact.one 'becameError', (result) =>
  # code does not get here for some reason
  transaction.rollback()
  #display some error message

transaction.commit()
```

If a 403 error happens then the above `becameError` handler does not get invoked and the object's state machine is left in the `rootState.error` state and any subsequent attempts to set a property on the object will fail because of the now infamous and dreaded:

```
uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `willSetProperty` on <Radium.Contact:ember2286:17> while in state rootState.error. Called with {reference: [object Object], store: <Radium.Store:ember3219>, name: name}
```

My thinking is that I can override the `didError` method:

```
didError: function(store, type, record, xhr) {
  if (xhr.status === 422) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText),
        serializer = get(this, 'serializer'),
        errors = serializer.extractValidationErrors(type, json);

    store.recordWasInvalid(record, errors);
  } else {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
},
```

My question is how do I get an object back into a usable state after the state machine has transitioned to `rootState.error`.